# Can a Regex expression achieve this sort of extraction?

Tags: c#

I have this string:

<: user | protocol://user-id/951480451967631360 :>**Someone**<:> **something something!**

I'm not sure if using regex I could end strip up the <:><:> part and end up with something like this:

**Someone something something!**

This is all in C#

Comment: Yes, you can do that with regexes. But for that you need to learn them. The sooner you start - the sooner you'll be able to do that.

Comment: Does anybody have any good resources for learning to work with regexes?

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest regex for that would be:

Find `<[^>]*>` and replace with nothing.

In c#:

```
Regex rgx = new Regex("<[^>]*>");
string result = rgx.Replace(yourString,"");
```

Comment: Works great.  Then I just replace "<:>" with an empty string.  Thanks a lot!